# Running Nextjs app on Linux Mint is giving me this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

[Screenshot of the logged error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCtHF.png)

I initialized a new Nextjs app using npx create-next-app and then typed npm run dev and got this error

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs you can solve with util:

```
var util= require('util');
var encoder = new util.TextEncoder('utf-8');
```

Comment: where do I add this?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to update to the latest version of Nodejs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).